# Merge multiple images dynamicallly with PHP

Tags: php, merge, sprite

I want to merge several image from a folder, into one image.
I've managed to do it with two images, but I don't like this method, because what if my folder has over 10 pictures?

```
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');
imagealphablending($image1, true);
imagesavealpha($image1, true);
imagecopy($image1, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
imagepng($image1, 'image3.png');
```

My question how can I access my folder and get all of my images without having to type $image1, $image2...over and over? Also can I do it in a Class?

Thanks everyone!

PS: I'm new to PHP but you can still be technical, the objective is to learn so I don't mind.

Comment: _"because what if my folder has over 10 pictures?"_ - what about it, then you simply repeat the same process another 9+ times. Hint: If the same thing needs to be done multiple times, only with different input data - that's what _functions_ are for.

Comment: _"My question how can I access my folder and get all of my images without having to type $image1, $image2...over and over?"_ - that part is really one, regarding which you should do a bit of basic research - how to get a list of files in a folder, that is anything but a new topic.